# MYSQL Using Subquery Result in Insert

Tags: mysql, database

I some data that I would like to insert into another table. In particular, I'm getting some ID values from the table guest_list_parties, and would like to pass those into the table guest_list_parties_secondary.

The party_id is what is being returned by the subquery; 2031 is the secondary_event_id I would like to pass along with every record.

However, MYSQL reports with an error, stating:
     'Subquery returns more than 1 row'

My code:

```
INSERT INTO guest_list_parties_secondary (party_id, secondary_event_id)

VALUES((SELECT id
FROM guest_list_parties
WHERE event_id = 31919),2031)
```

Any help/direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your insert statement expects two columns to be supplied: `party_id` and `secondary_event_id`. [`VALUES()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html) expects literal values, you should just explicitly select `2031` in your query:

```
INSERT INTO guest_list_parties_secondary (party_id, secondary_event_id)
SELECT id, 2031
FROM guest_list_parties
WHERE event_id = 31919;
```